# Varibles cannot change while I use rxjs operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8];
rxjs.from(a.splice(0, 3))
      .pipe(
        rxjs.concatMap(val => {
          return rxjs.of(val).pipe(rxjs.delay(Math.random() * 1000));
        }),
        rxjs.repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(rxjs.delay(2000))),
        rxjs.tap(val => {
          console.log(a);
        }),
        rxjs.takeWhile(val => a.length > 0)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

In above,I suppose it will console.log [4,5,6],and then [7,8],and then stop,but while it always console.log [4,5,6]。
I wonder know why it is and how to achive I want.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate the description of your problem? I don't understand it. What do you want to achieve? Why would you expect `a` to change the size to `0`? `a.splice(0, 3)` is evaluated once. It removes the first three elements from `a` and returns them.

Comment: I am not understand why it logs [4,5,6,7,8] forever。I think a is [4,5,6,7,8] after a.splice(0, 3) at first time.Then a is [7,8] after a.splice(0, 3) at second time。How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: `a.splice(0, 3)` is called once at the beginning and never again. Can you describe, what you want to achieve in context with the delays?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call splice inside the pipe

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8];
rxjs.from(a.splice(0, 3))
      .pipe(
        rxjs.concatMap(val => {
          return rxjs.of(val).pipe(rxjs.delay(Math.random() * 1000));
        }),
        rxjs.repeatWhen(completed => completed.pipe(rxjs.delay(2000))),
        rxjs.tap(val => {
          console.log(a);
          a.splice(0, 3);
        }),
        rxjs.takeWhile(val => a.length > 0)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```